# Android Webview displays content as Raw HTML

Tags: android

I am using the following code for rendering a dynamically created html string on a webview. It works properly on my device. But on one of the user's device, the webview displays the raw html tags and content instead of rendering properly.

I cannot reproduce the issue on my devices. What can be cause for this issue to happen. Any device level settings? or Encoding related issue?

`String htmlContent = "<html><body> .... </body></html>";`

`webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlContent, "text/HTML", "UTF-8", null);`

Comment: did you try to use `text/html` (with lower case letters) as type?

Comment: @Henry, I suspect this should be the issue. But with 'text/HTML' (with upper case) it works on my device. One of the user reported this issue, but still I did not get the device model or version. I will update. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It works for me.

```
WebSettings settings = mDesc.getSettings();
settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
mDesc.loadData(mDescText, "text/html; charset=utf-8",null);
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this code. But the code that i already have also working on my device. The issue only happen on one of the user's device. Do you have any idea on why the existing code did not worked on user's device.

Comment: can you provide the device name and OS version of the device?

Comment: I don't have that information, I have requested for those information already. I will update. thanks

Comment: I got same issue in an HTC device. thats comes because of javascript enabling issue. Please accept the answer if you found it helpful

Comment: Thanks for information. I am now trying to reproduce the issue on my device. From your comment, I understand that it may happen if the javascript is enabled/disabled on browser application level settings on some or all devices.